# UserProfileProperties: You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

C#:

```
PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);
PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetMyProperties();

try
{
    clientContext.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.Write("error occur while retrieve person properties ", ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

AppManifest.xml

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

> After providing tenant permission it still showing - You do not have
>   permission to perform this action or access this resource.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Funny, I had the same issue today, but in PnP Powershell

Comment: It resolved after: `<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="Read" />`